# Android : Load a large file of 1.7GB as a MappedByteBufer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I need to load inside android a large file `1.7GB` as a MappedByteBuffer at once and not as chunks.

I get `OutOfMemory: Map failed` error. Based on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory#CheckHowMuchMemory) there is a hard limit on the heap size allotted for each app.  I have tested it and the maximum is ~ `1.1GB` ie I can load a dummy file as a MappedByteBuffer that is that long.

Nothing changes if I create an emulator with really large heap memory and RAM. Also no luck with setting `largeHeap = true` at manifest.

As this is a showcase and it is not going into production, I want to know **if I can override this limit**.

Anyone has an answer?

Code that I am using to load the file:

```
private fun loadModelFromInternalStorage(context: Context, modelName: String): MappedByteBuffer {
    val modelPath: String = context.filesDir.path + "/" + modelName
    val file = File(modelPath)
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
    Log.v(TAG, file.length().toString())
    Log.v(TAG, Int.MAX_VALUE.toString())
    return inputStream.channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, file.length())
}
```

The limit of the MappedByteBuffer is `Int.MAX_VALUE` which is bigger that the file's length.

Comment: Does updating the application manifest with [largeHeap=true](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) helps ?

Comment: Yes I have done this..nothing changes! Let me add this on the description.

Comment: Heap memory in android seems to be controlled by [dalvik.vm.heapsize](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp;l=826?q=dalvik.vm.heapsize&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject&start=101) when an application is launched. I think, unless you can change this property in the system partition you cannot have more heap. (mount system partition as rw and update it)